# `tlmgr update` fails with "Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, tex-live-utility

Tried to run `tlmgr update --self`, but it fails with this error message:

> `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: open tlpdb(http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device at /usr/local/texlive/2016/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 358.`

Now what can I do? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed TeXLive from tug.org using `./install-tl`.

Comment: I don't think this question belongs (suits/ falls into the global goal) this site, this will suit an SE that will deal especially with software.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the source file and this error is issued when `wget` fails to download the package database. I was using the repository `ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final`, and it seems that there is some intermittent non-availability (server is overloaded, or unstable connection). It had nothing to do with `wget` configuration (as hinted by @chbrown), just trying again some time later worked.

Answer (score 1):

The message is cryptic, but I ran into the same thing with TeXLive 2018. I used `opensnoop` (= `dtrace`) to monitor what files `tlmgr` was opening, and noted that it was reading my `~/.wgetrc` configuration file, which had custom settings for `header`, `user_agent`, etc.

I removed that file, reran `tlmgr`, and it breezed through :). YMMV, since I have no idea what "Inappropriate ioctl for device" has to do with performing HTTP requests.

**tl;dr**: Remove your `~/.wgetrc`.